# Locate an iOS app directory using a CFBundleIdentifier

Tags: ios, shell

What I want to do is locate an iOS apps directory because they use a random udid for the folder name i.e `var/mobile/sd65f4s65d4f65sd4f65s4df654/awesome.app`

So I want to get that location directory by using the apps CFBundleIdentifier which is in the Info.plist file in the app folder.

From the research I've done it seems I can use plutil from the cydia package ericasutils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get path to determine resource path, you can use that API:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];
```